# Seemingly basic integration by parts question

Tags: calculus

I am having a bit of a mind block with the most elementary calculus technique. Trying to integrate

$\int_0^\infty x\Phi(x) \mathrm{d}x$

by parts by differentiating $x$ and integrating $\Phi$, how does one deal with the constant arising when integrating $\Phi$?

ie. what should one write in the position -- below:

$\int_0^\infty x\Phi(x) \mathrm{d}x = (x\int_{--}^x\Phi(y)\mathrm{d}y)\rvert^\infty_0 - \int_0^\infty\int_{--}^x \Phi(y)\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x $

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any constant, because the per partes rule says that

$$\int_a^b u(x) v'(x) dx = u(x)v(x)|_a^b -\int_a^b u'(x)v(x)dx$$

So if you change $v(x)$ with $\bar v(x) = v(x) + C$, nothing changes, since $v' = \bar v'$